# Can anyone explain how this image protection trick is done?

Tags: graphics, png

If you look at this image [image: Protected Image]

you can see it just fine (with anti theft diagonals over it.) in a browser but trying copying it and opening it up in your favorite image editor. The image is mostly black with the lines and an almost impossible to see version of the shape in editors.

I'm guessing they messed with the png meta data that browsers don't generally read but editors do?

Answer (score 2):

It's not image protection. The file contains an alpha channel. The area between the hash lines has an alpha of 0, which means transparent. Many image viewers do strange things in this situation. They may, for example, clear the background to black before drawing the image.

Comment: I thought that too, but I can load the image up in photoshop and put a white layer underneath it and the image is not transparent.

Comment: When I load it in Photoshop and put a white layer below it, I see the light hash marks over the white layer, just as I'd expect from an alpha channel. I'm not sure what you mean. If I take it into Apple Motion, I can see that the colors read out as: RGBA = (0.267, 0.267, 0.251, 0.059) in the hash marks area. (The alpha varies from 0 to about 0.06 over the hash marks.)